How can I efficiently handle gas costs when deploying Ethereum smart contracts?"
I'm relatively new to Ethereum development and I'm currently working on deploying smart contracts to the Ethereum mainnet. One concern I have is managing gas costs effectively to ensure that my deployments are economical.
Could you please share some strategies or best practices for minimizing gas costs when deploying smart contracts? Additionally, are there any tools or techniques that can help optimize gas usage?
Thanks in advance for your insights!

As Awais mentioned, review each line of code. To put some more details on this.
Gas optimization is a thing that needs time. You shouldn't do it along with the development process, that consumes more time with minimal outcome. First, write the contract and test the logic. If everything works fine then start the gas and security review.
To find out the places that can be improved, you should first know the tricks or you should have a sense of how different ways of writing the code use different gas units.
For example, a payable function costs less gas than a normal function(Explained here).
Using unchecked blocks for loops or any arithmetic operation reduces gas cost, but you also need to know when should you use these tricks so that the contract security is not compromised.
This Gas optimization book by Rareskill is great for learning all those tricks.
You can also check Gaslite contracts, where they write highly optimized contracts. Gaslite's whole business is around gas optimizations, so you'll learn a lot from their contracts.

First manually review each line of the code  and ask yourself why this line is here? Do I really need it?  and how it can be optimized, delete the unnecessary mappings, state variables and loops, you can use AI tools (Gemini and GPT) for optimizing the contract. You can use Blockchain tool to learn about foundary about gas estimation foundary book
